# IPhone Xib size descrepncies with actual Iphone

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

When I create an .xib file the default width is 320 and the default height is 568.

But these are not the correct sizes for width and height of an actual iPhone screen, which is 640x1136 for a Retina iPhone or 640x960 for the iPhone 4.

Neither of these is the default .xib's width and length.

Can someone explain the discrepancy or where my thinking is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the correct size. Retina graphics have double the number of pixels, but your user interface has the same usable size (320x480/568). You should have 2 copies of your images, non-retina version (image.png) and a retina version (image@2x.png).

Comment: why 480/568? if retina is double it should just be 568

Comment: @bf613, the size in in "points", not pixels. Retina has two pixels per point.

Comment: 480 is the height of the iPhone 3/4/4S, 568 is the height of the iPhone 5. The pixels are then doubled for retina displays (so iPhone 5 is 1136px high by nature, and iPhone 4+ is 960px). As @MarcusAdams said, the useable size is defined by the number of 'Points' not 'Pixels'.